# Ember data createRecord not working: "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js

I'm using Ember data for a web app and everything has been working pretty smoothly until I tried saving some new data using "createRecord".

This is the gist of the code:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    namespace: 'api'
  })
});

App.Training = DS.Model.extend({
  dateTimestamp: DS.attr('number'),
  dateTime: DS.attr('string'),
  dateDay: DS.attr('number'),
  dateWeekday: DS.attr('string'),
  dateMonth: DS.attr('string'),
  teacherId: DS.attr('number'),
  teacherFirstName: DS.attr('string'),
  teacherPhoneNumber: DS.attr('string'),
  teacherAvatarCss: DS.attr('string'),
  spotName: DS.attr('string'),
  spotNamespace: DS.attr('string'),
  spotId: DS.attr('number'),
  spotHasPicture: DS.attr('string'),
  spotPictureCss: DS.attr('string'),
  spotUrl: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I've built a simple REST api for the backend, and fetching data works great:

```
App.KalenderRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('training'); // This works!
  }
});
```

I then try to call an action in my Controller to save a new record:

```
App.KalenderController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    addTraining: function(){
        var store = this.store;
        store.createRecord('training', {
            spotId: 5
        }); // This does not work :(
    }
  }
});
```

If I've understood correctly, this should send a POST AJAX request to /api/training with the spotId parameter. However, the POST request is never sent it seems, and instead my console says:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Full stack trace:

```
DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.createRecord ember-data.prod.js:1575
App.KalenderController.Em.ArrayController.extend.actions.addTraining App.js:197
Mixin.create.send ember.prod.js:15207
runRegisteredAction ember.prod.js:34269
Backburner.run ember.prod.js:7947
apply ember.prod.js:7779
run ember.prod.js:6415
handleRegisteredAction ember.prod.js:34267
(anonymous function) ember.prod.js:22582
m.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
r.handle
```

Is there anyone who has any idea why this is? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Without knowing the exact version of Ember-Data you're using, we can't pinpoint the line that is causing your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The store doesn't need to be defined since 1.0beta+ of Ember Data.  You just define adapters and serializers.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});

App.Training = DS.Model.extend({
  dateTimestamp: DS.attr('number'),
  dateTime: DS.attr('string'),
  dateDay: DS.attr('number'),
  dateWeekday: DS.attr('string'),
  dateMonth: DS.attr('string'),
  teacherId: DS.attr('number'),
  teacherFirstName: DS.attr('string'),
  teacherPhoneNumber: DS.attr('string'),
  teacherAvatarCss: DS.attr('string'),
  spotName: DS.attr('string'),
  spotNamespace: DS.attr('string'),
  spotId: DS.attr('number'),
  spotHasPicture: DS.attr('string'),
  spotPictureCss: DS.attr('string'),
  spotUrl: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Additionally no ajax call is made until you call save on the record

```
var record = this.store.createRecord('training',{
  spotId:1
});
record.save();
```

Example (with delay for fun): http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/856/edit

Comment: Wow, it turns out Bower has installed an old version of Ember data and that's what was causing all the trouble (I was running 0.13 instead of 1.0.0). Thank you so much for the detailed answer, it helped me identify the problem!